# Flutter 'Compute' memory leak - How do I retire heap variables used by compute instance?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use a [compute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html) instance in my mobile application to reduce [jank](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/ui-performance) when deserializing a bunch of downloaded JSON into objects.

When I implement the deserialization method using [compute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html), the heap keeps **both** the passed JSON *and* the returned deserialized objects (in a list) INDEFINITELY. GC is triggering normally but is not removing the objects from the heap, even when the method has closed and the parent/calling objects had been retired. As such, when using the DevTools memory profiler, it shows runaway memory consumption - the heap just keeps getting bigger.

[image: Normal memory profile] Normal Memory Profile - memory usage hovers around 45MB when the deserialization method is called directly (but it causes jank in the app)

[image: Runaway memory profile] Runaway Memory Profile - memory usage increases linearly and is never retired when the deserialization method is called via compute (but it doesn't cause jank in the app)

```dart
static Stream<EventCommitInfoModel> getEventsAfterDate(DateTime date) async* {

    // variable defs for scope reuse

    while (count < maxCount && retryCount > 0) {
      try {
        json = await http.read(url);

        // currentEvents = await compute(EventModel.fromJsonArray, json);
        currentEvents = EventModel.fromJsonArray(json);

        db = await AppStateModel.database;
        await db.upsertEventModels(currentEvents);
        yield new InfoModel(maxCount, currentEvents.length);
      }
      catch (ex) {

        // try again or close

      }
    }

    print("stream is closing.");
  }
```

In the code above, the relevant lines begin with "currentEvents = ". The normal memory behavior is seen with:

```dart
  currentEvents = EventModel.fromJsonArray(json);
```

and the runaway memory behavior is seen with:

```dart
  currentEvents = await compute(EventModel.fromJsonArray, json);
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT CHANGING EventModel.fromJsonArray to an async method has *NO* impact on any of the profiling above. Nor does changing it to async cause the jank to go away. I have already considered that. I *can* add artificial delays into the code in order to introduce async splits in the mapping method, but that's NOT what I want to do here - I need the data to return as fast as possible, which is why using compute is ideal.

Even after "stream is closing" is printed, and the stream is closed, and the parent object is retired from the hierarchy and collected, any memory associated with the compute method is never retired.

How do I get the compute instance to retire memory properly? Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi sir, have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: The issue is still outstanding. The project was mostly abandoned following this issue as I could not suitably resolve the performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same issue on flutter 2.2.3

All `data` I pass as argument to the compute are kept in memory - `await compute(exampleGlobalFunction, data)`.

I checked it in `Flutter DevTools` / `Memory` tab and the instances of data are never released. If I call the function directly (without compute) then data are properly released.

EDIT: I think I found the solution - created a github issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86470

Answer (score 1):

Without more code, what seems to be happening is that the stream you are creating is never having actually closing. So the stream remains open, and thus has hooks into the json objects which GC cannot then remove.

You imply in your problem statement that the stream is getting closed:

`Even after "stream is closing" is printed, and the stream is closed, and ...`

... But a print statement that the stream is closing doesn't close the stream. Just getting to the end of the code block does not close the stream either (especially for a broadcast stream), at least afaik.

Also per the dart documentation they don't recommend operating on streams directly; https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#final-hints for exactly this reason too. They recommend using a stream controller.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about old Flutter version, but the current version of `Channel master, 1.21.0-6.0.pre.41` doesn't have any problems with `compute` function.

I am using it in the project and seems like memory is not growing.

[image]

The main point `compute` is killing the isolate under the hood. Isolate releases it's memory at the moment of killing.

```
/// The dart:io implementation of [isolate.compute].
Future<R> compute<Q, R>(isolates.ComputeCallback<Q, R> callback, Q message, { String? debugLabel }) async {

  ... other code ...

  resultPort.close();
  errorPort.close();
  isolate.kill();
  Timeline.finishSync();
  return result.future;
}
```

If you are using Isolate.spawn directly - make sure you keep the instance and kill it manually after the work is done. I am using this approach as well.

```
release() {
  _subscription.cancel();
  _controller.close();
  _isolate.kill(
    priority: Isolate.immediate,
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm on Flutter 1.22.5 - and isolates still cause memory leak - I've removed everything from isolate function - just call 

await compute(_emptyFunction, null);

Future<void> _emptyFunction(Params params) async {
}

Answer (score 0):

When using **Isolates** the callback arguments must be a top level function.

> The callback argument must be a top-level function, not a closure or
>   an instance or static method of a class.

You can try something like:

```
class EventsRepo  {
  static const URL = 'https://some-json.com/events';

  @override
  Future<List<Event>> fetchEvents(http.Client client) async {
    final response = await client.get(URL);
    return compute(parseJson, response.body);
  }
}

// Top level function
List<Event> parseJson(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
  return parsed.map<Event>((json) => EventModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

Please notice the top level function, hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to make a response. However, I have already tried using a top-level function, and unfortunately the results are the same. Declaring the callback either inside or outside of a class did not make any difference - the memory still runs away and is never retired from the heap.